# Is It Possible to Put non (Static Const Integral) Types in C++ Header.h File

Tags: c++, header, include, definition

I have a class in MyClass.h file:

```
// MyClass.h
#ifndef __MY_CLASS_H__
#define __MY_CLASS_H__

#include <string>

class MyClass
{
    static const std::string MyStaticConstString; // I cannot initialize it here, because it's not an integral type.
};

// OK, let's define/initialize it out side of the class declaration
// static
const std::string MyClass::MyStaticConstString = "Value of MyStaticConstString";

#endif
```

The problem is, the compiler will complain "Multiple definition" if this file is included for more than one times.

So I have to move the definition of `MyStaticConstString` to MyClass.cpp file.  But what if `MyClass` is part of a library, and I want my users to see the const static value in the MyClass.h file, which makes sense, because it's a static const value.

How should I do?  I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks.

Peter

Comment: In C#, you can always put the initialization in the class declaration.

Comment: @Neil, what I meant is C++ member initialization rules are really frustrating, in my personal opinion.  I did not get any benefit from these rules.  Let me know if they do have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for the same reason you can't put global variables in headers, const-qualified or not. Document your constant instead (if it's a constant, then why should users care about its value anyway?).

Also, don't prepend your identifiers with underscores (`__MY_CLASS_H__`), they're reserved for implementation stuff.

Comment: Yes, it's possible that the std or boost guys use `__THIS_STYLE_H__` guide.  Hmm, I will rename it to `THIS_STYLE_H`.

Comment: @Peter If the boost guys are doing it (which I doubt), then they are doing it wrong. Those names are reserved for the implementation, specifically for things like the std:: namespace for your specific compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- Names like __MY_CLASS_H__ cannot be created by people like you or me.
- std::strings are not integral types

Answer (score 1):

No.

What should you do?

Do this in header:

```
//myclass.h

 // MyClass.h
 #ifndef MY_CLASS_H
 #define MY_CLASS_H

class MyClass
{
    static const std::string MyStaticConstString; // I cannot initialize it here, because it's not an integral type.
};

extern std::string some_global_variable; //declare this with extern keyword

 #endif //MY_CLASS_H
```

And do this in source file:

```
//myclass.cpp
#include "myclass.h"

const std::string MyClass::MyStaticConstString = "Value of MyStaticConstString";

std::string some_global_variable = "initialization";
```

Remember names prefixed with underscore are reserved, don't use them. Use `MY_CLASS_H`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Yes, that's what I am doing.  But what if MyClass is part of a library, and I want my users to see the const static value in the MyClass.h file, which makes sense, because it's a static const value.  (As Cat++ points out, we should put it in the documentation)